# Resolver captchas utilizando PHP

Tags: php, captcha, imagick

Pesquisei no Google, em fóruns mas não achei nada satisfatório para as minhas necessidades. Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma solução para resolver [captchas como esta](http://www8.dataprev.gov.br/SipaINSS/faces/resource/1430760703586/CAPTCHA.xhtml?rsrc=captcha) utilizando PHP. Tenho conhecimento básico sobre as bibliotecas Imagick e GD, entretando estou a procurar alguma biblioteca ou coisa do tipo, mas se não existir, um bom *know how* e dicas de como eu poderia estar resolvendo essas captchas também são bem-vindas.

**Exemplo de captcha a ser resolvida**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Poderia identificar as letras nas imagens usando algum algoritmo de Inteligência Artificial e assim te ajudar a resolver o problema.

Ou mesmo fazer uma análise pixel a pixel da imagem e identificar manualmente a letra.

Uma boa ferramenta que poderia te ajudar nisso em php é essa [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).